# Does TFS 2010 meet our requirements for source control and deployment

Tags: msbuild, web-deployment, server-configuration

Our company currently use sourcecontol and milestone/ticket tracking from Assembla.com, build automation and developement environment deployment with cc.net and visual studio for publishing to test and production environment. We currently are using build configuration in visual studio to set up connection strings and app settings, while we manually change urls for web services in web.config. We recently became silver partner and thus get TFS, etc licenses. I am wondering if a change to TFS would provide the options we need for the following requirements:

We have 3 environments, dev, test and prod, each with the following machines (All on Windows Server 2008 R2):

- Web server with about 30 different web sites all in asp.net
- Server running 5 windows services
- Database server with 10-15 different databases in sql server 2005 +
  ssrs 2005

We need the following:

- Source control with branch, tag and merge
- Continuous Integration with automatic deployment to dev environment
- Tickets/Work items with attachment and documentation linking/wiki
  linking
- Milestones/Releases
- Versioning/sourcecontrol of database schema
- Deployment to test / prod environment without having to manually
  configure application or execute sql files
- Quick rollback in case of errors after deployment

Answer (score 2):

Some these items will require a little configuration and customizations, but yes TFS does all that.